# Magento Editing Grid Items Not Retrieving Data

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform

I am creating Custom Admin Module.

Everything working fine but when I click on grid row to edit item it redirects correctly but the text field doesn’t contains any data.

But if I input some text into the text filrd and click on Save, the fields gets updated correctly.

And i am using this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFoplTYKFVc. Thanks in Advance

**Below is my code:**

```
public function editAction()
{
    if ($eventId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('event_id')) {
        Mage::register('current_event', Mage::getModel('example/event')->load('$eventId'));
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('example/events');

    $this->_addContent(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('example/adminhtml_event_edit')
     );

    return $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And here is the form.php

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Event_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _initFormValues()
    {
       //for editing existing events
        if ($event = Mage::registry('current_event')) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            //Manipulate the data
            $this->getForm()->setValues($data);
        }

        //in order to keeo post data during a failed save
        if ($data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getData('event_form_data',true)) {
            $this->getForm()->setValues($data);
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array('id' => 'edit_form',
                  'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                  'method' => 'post'
            )
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',array('legend'=> Mage::helper('example')->__('General Information'),'class'=> 'fieldset-wide'));

        $fieldset->addField('name','text',array(
            'name'    => 'name',
            'label'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Event Name'),
            'title'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Event Name'),
            'required' => true
        ));

        $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

        $fieldset->addField('start','date',array(
            'name'     => 'start',
            'format'   => $dateFormatIso,
            'image'    => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'label'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
            'title'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
            'required' => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('end','date',array(
            'name'     => 'end',
            'format'   => $dateFormatIso,
            'image'    => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'label'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
            'title'   => Mage::helper('example')->__('Start Date'),
            'required' => true
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);


        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
Mage::register('current_event', Mage::getModel('example/event')->load('$eventId'));
```

To:

```
Mage::register('current_event', Mage::getModel('example/event')->load($eventId));
```

Comment: This didnt work :(

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Please, Do you have a link to any magento tutorial where i can learn the Earlier method you suggested?

Comment: I'll look for, but maybe _initFormValues() is better. I'll leave a comment aus soon I'm back.